# AutoHotkey - How to set two keys pressed at same time to send another key

Tags: key, autohotkey, remap

I read in some post that Autohotkey allow to set two keys pressed at same time to send another key, i.e. letter B and number 1 pressed at same time wil send letter P.
It is posible? how is the script? thanks advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom key combination by typing the name of each key separated by an ampersand, like this:

```
B & 1::P
```

Keep in mind, though, that the first key will lose it's original function. To work around it, using the `B & 1` example, make a hotkey for "b" that sends "b".

Comment: You can also add a tilde to not lose original function:
~B & 1::P